# Allow UTF-8 characters in the user slug part of URL

Tags: urls, author, slug

I want to be able to specify a custom slug for an author URL that may contain UTF-8 characters.

I used the plugin Edit Author Slug but it does not accept UTF8 characters like accented characters, Arabic or Hebrew letters.